# add data into an object list index by index

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two lists of data with the same size.
I am adding the two lists to an array of objects but the Syllabus list is completely added to the object list before being added to the Article list. My challenge is add data to the Syllabus list and the Article list simultaneously.
For instance if the index of syllabus is zero, let it get the index of the Syllabus and of the Article and add it to the object list before moving
to the index of 1 till the last index so as the index of Syllabus grows so does the Article until they get to the last element in the list.
Below is my attempt but it's not working index by index

Here is the object list

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
List <Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();

List <Syllabus> syllabus = articleOfAssociationDao.findByType(type);


    obj.addAll(syllabus); //adding to an object list
    for(int i =0; i < syllabus.size(); i++) {
        List<Article> articleContent = articleContentDao.findBySyllabus(syllabus.get(i));
        obj.addAll( articleContent); //adding to an object list
    }
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. What is `obj`? Do you get an exception? If so, what? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have shown the object list. The challenge I have is that if index 0 is added to the object from Syllabus then get the index of article and add the list to the object list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following work?

```
for(int i =0; i < syllabus.size(); i++) {
    List<Article> articleContent = articleContentDao.findBySyllabus(syllabus.get(i));
    obj.add(syllabus.get(i));
    obj.addAll(articleContent);
}
```